# Changing div/span colour when scrolling past elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar which pops out when the hamburger is clicked (the CodePen provided is not working with this but its not important for what I'm trying to achieve, it works within my project).

The issue I am having is that my site follows a black and white theme and I am looking to have the span elements change colour to white if they are over a dark section. I've seen a couple of CodePens on this but they are only for scrolling down once rather than changing multiple times, as I have more than one dark section.

I am thinking I will have to incorporate this into my existing JS perhaps, or would I be more efficient creating a new function? I am unsure how to select the span and change its background colour when over a dark element, I think I will need to make up new classes for these such as 'dark' or 'light', but I am struggling with how to compose the function.

In my head I am reading it as 'If the section class = dark then span bg colour should = white, else section class = light then span bg should = black'.

I hope this makes sense, I'm trying to learn JS so this is probably a really simple solution. I understand what I am trying to achieve and the general layout still not confident in writing functions yet, but getting to grips with it!

```
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">

                    <div class="nav" id="navBar">
                        <div id="navBtn">
                           <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <ul>


                    <li><a href="#about">
                            <p class="scrollto-aboutus animated fadeInUp">Home</p>
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#overview">
                            <p class="scrollto-overview animated fadeInUp">text</p>
                        </a></li>

                </ul>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
<section class="section-black new-section dark"></section>
<section class="section-white new-section light"></section>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    width: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

#navBtn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#navBtn span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


#navBtn span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#navBtn span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 15px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#navBtn span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}




/* --- nav after */


#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    left: -300px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sidebar a {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#sidebar p {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
}

.section-black { 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: black;
}

.section-white { 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: white;
}
```

JS

```
function toggleSidebar() {
    document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
    var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.new-section'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < sections.length; ++i) {
        sections[i].classList.toggle('new_section--active');
    }
};  


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navBtn').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

Heres a really terrible CodePen example: https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/oOPGQQ

Comment: you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220268/change-font-color-on-scroll-based-on-a-div)? Check the accepted answer

Comment: Precisely, that is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work great with my existing code actually, but I may be able to tweak it, it seems there is too much in this function for what I need, and it is knocking out most of my other JS so back to the drawing board.

Comment: @CaitlinMooney Since this question was previously asked and that you found what you were looking for, you can safely delete this one

Comment: @Jake the code didn't work for me, it doesn't take into account the span elements, and also does not account for the dark sections which are don't have a black background colour, but contain a dark image for instance. Overall it is what I am trying to achieve but I need to have it dependant on the section ID of dark or light.

Answer (score 2):

> This is an attempt to help someone who is familiar with HTML and CSS,
>   but not Javascript, set up a simple effect that will change their
>   page’s background colour when the user scrolls down.
>
> **Step 1: CSS** First of all, we need to set a beginning background colour on our body:
>
> ```
> body {
>    background: green;
> }
> ```
>
> Next, we’ll make a new CSS class with the background colour we want to
>   switch to when the user scrolls down:
>
> ```
> .changeColor {
>    background: white;
> }
> ```
>
> **Step 2: Javascript** Make a new text document called scripts.js in the same folder as your index.html file. Paste the following code in
>   and save:
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>    $(window).scroll(function () {
>       if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
>          $(‘body’).addClass(‘changeColor’)
>       }
>       if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
>          $(‘body’).removeClass(‘changeColor’)
>       }
>    });
> });
> ```
>
> If you’re a beginner like me, just glancing at this code probably
>   makes your eyes glaze over. But it’s actually quite simple. When our
>   visitor scrolls more than 50 pixels down, we add the class changeColor
>   to the body, changing the background from green to white. When they
>   scroll back up, we remove the class and the background goes back to
>   green.
>
> **Step 3: HTML** Finally, at the bottom of our HTML document, just before the  tag, we want to paste in the following text:
>
> ```
>    <script src=”https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
>    <script src=”scripts.js”></script>
> </body>
> ```
>
> The first tag is pointing to a general jQuery library hosted by
>   Google. The second tag is pointing to the Javascript file we just
>   made.
>
> **Step 4** (optional): Make the background change smoother with some CSS IMHO the effect looks nicer when when the new background colour
>   fades in, rather than a sudden change. All we need for this is a
>   simple CSS effect called “transition”.
>
> In our CSS file, let’s change the body code to:
>
> ```
> body {
>   background: green;
>   transition: 0.3s all;
> }
> ```
>
> 0.3s is the amount of time the transition effect takes. Feel free to change this.
>
> **Step 5: Experiment!** Once you understand the basic idea of how it works, you can edit your CSS and Javascript files to add, remove and
>   change any element you want when the user scrolls down.
>
> For example, create a new CSS class:
>
> ```
> .displayNone {
>    display: none;
> }
> ```
>
> And in the Javascript file, add this below “> 50”:
>
> ```
> $(‘header’).addClass(‘displayNone’)
> ```
>
> and this below “< 50”:
>
> ```
> $(‘header’).removeClass(‘displayNone’)
> ```
>
> Now your header element will disappear when the user scrolls down.
>
> Here is how my code turned out for all the elements on my project, if
>   you’re curious:
>
> ```
> $(function() {
> $(window).scroll(function () {
>    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
>       $(‘body’).addClass(‘colorChange’)
>       $(‘header’).addClass(‘displayNone’)
>       $(‘nav’).removeClass(‘navBackgroundStart’)
>       $(‘nav ul’).addClass(‘addBlackBackground’)
>    } 
>    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
>       $(‘body’).removeClass(‘colorChange’)
>       $(‘header’).removeClass(‘displayNone’)
>       $(‘nav’).addClass(‘navBackgroundStart’)
>       $(‘nav ul’).removeClass(‘addBlackBackground’)
>    } 
> });
> });
> ```

https://medium.com/@_patrickcameron/a-complete-beginner-s-guide-to-changing-background-colour-on-scroll-using-jquery-fce686d55049

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this yesterday! Thank you for the explanation, between this and the answer above I think I'll be able to achieve exactly what I am hoping to. Get back to you soon!

Answer (score 1):

you can just use css property mix blend mode "mix-blend-mode".

Using the blend-mode property, you can blend the background layers (image or color) of an element. Blend modes are defined as a value and they specify how to blend or mix the colors of the background image with the color, or other background images,  behind it.

mix-blend-mode : difference,
If your element to change the background-colour is set to white, and the background color of yoursite, or even the image it scrolls over is also white, the colour will be displayed black.

And there you go

```
#element-to-blend{
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

CodePen example: https://codepen.io/DamienSellier/pen/dyGeNom